# How to run "npm install" before every pm2-restart?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, pm2

I am trying to automatically deploy a hobby-node-app to my Raspberry Pi 2 via PM2.

The PM2 package "autopull" automatically pulls the latest commit from the checked out branch of my Bitbucket-Repo (in case of the RBPi 2 -> master) and restarts PM2.

However, if I add new dependencies in my bower.json or package.json in the latest commit, those would not be installed by PM2. Is there a way to have PM2 automatically run "npm install && bower install" after every git pull?

I would also be satisfied with a different setup that would achieve the same thing.

Comment: I think you should open an issue on that package. Seems like something `autopull` should do.

Answer (score 6):

Try a git hook! Put this inside your repo's .git/hooks/post-merge file, create it if you don't have one. Make sure the file is executable.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo " GIT POST-MERGE NPM INSTALL"
exec npm install

echo " GIT POST-MERGE BOWER UPDATE"
exec bower update
```