# Is there a way to get PM2 to run npm install when package.json updates?

Tags: pm2

I set up pm2 with a watch, so each time a git pull is done, it auto reloads the app.
This works, unless the app dependencies have changed, then it needs to run `npm install` first.  This causes pm2 to restart and crash over and over until the install is done.

Is there a way to have pm2 watch automatically run `npm install` before restarting?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @AhmetYildirim I sadly have not found a solution yet.

Comment: @AhmetYildirim This answer might kind of work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648761/how-to-run-npm-install-before-every-pm2-restart?rq=1 But I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way but, you can add script in package.json

...
   scripts: {
       ....
       "postinstall" "pm2 restart (your process id from pm2)"
   }
...
Run pm2 start (your entry file server) and get process id.
Always run npm install and then pm2 will restart process after that
 Note that you need to install pm2 globally using "npm i -g pm2" on the machine